# onclick event executing the same function differently

Tags: javascript, html, anonymous-function

I have a test function:

```js
function test(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    console.log(element);
}
```

which I want to use as a callback when my button `<button id="testbtn">afsdasd</button>` is pressed. If I do this:

```
document.getElementById('testbtn').onclick = () => { 
    test(this); 
};
```

I get the following output:
[image]
However, if I do this:

```
document.getElementById('testbtn').onclick = function() { 
    test(this); 
};
```

the output is different:
[image]
Why? I thought both versions were exactly the same?

Comment: That's because arrow functions do not have their own `this` context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is an arrow function while the second one is a regular function. Arrow functions do not have their own `this` binding, so they will search this in the next outer lexical scope. In your case the enclosing lexical scope for the arrow function is the Window object.

> An arrow function does not have its own this. The this value of the
>   enclosing lexical scope is used; arrow functions follow the normal
>   variable lookup rules. So while searching for this which is not
>   present in current scope, an arrow function ends up finding the this
>   from its enclosing scope. [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions](http://Documentation)